# How to blacklist specific character, but also allow any other character or no character, without using negative lookahead

Tags: regex

I'm trying to find a solution to a regex that can match anything after a string or nothing, but if there's something it can't be a dot .

is it possible to do without negative lookahead?

here's an example regex:

```
.*\.(cpl)[^.].*
```

now the string:

```
C:\Windows\SysWOW64\control.exe mlcfg32.cpl sounds
```

this one is matched, but if there's only:

```
C:\Windows\SysWOW64\control.exe mlcfg32.cpl
```

it's not matched because due to the dot blacklist it's searching for any character after cpl,if i use ? after the [^.] however it won't blacklist the . in case there's something else after, so it will capture this even if it shouldn't:

```
C:\Windows\SysWOW64\control.exe mlcfg32.cpl. sounds
```

can it be done without using negative lookaheads? - ?!

Comment: You can use: `.*\.cpl[^.\n]*$`

Comment: Maybe `.*\.(cpl)(?:[^.].*)?$`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
.*\.(cpl)(?:[^.].*)?$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/pPMOQD/1). *Details*:

- `.*` - zero or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible
- `\.` - a dot
- `(cpl)` - Group 1: `cpl`
- `(?:[^.].*)?` - an optional non-capturing group that matches a char other than `.` char and then zero or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: thanks, i did not specify however, that a dot can happen later in the string, this one won't match this case, even if it should: "C:\Windows\SysWOW64\control.exe mlcfg32.cpl sounds .whatever". the . can't happen only 1 char after .cpl

Comment: @AngeloPitarresi Are you sure? See [my regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/pPMOQD/2). My regex does the job as you expect.

Answer (score 2):

You may use this regex:

```bash
.*\.cpl(?:[^.].*|$)
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/vmdq2H/2)

**RegEx Breakdown:**

- `.*`: Match 0 or more of any character
- `\.cpl`: Match `.cpl`
- `(?:[^.].*|$)`: Match end of string or a non-dot followed by any text

Comment: thanks, i did not specify however, that a dot can happen later in the string, this one won't match this case, even if it should: 

"C:\Windows\SysWOW64\control.exe mlcfg32.cpl sounds .whatever"

the . can't happen only 1 char after .cpl

Comment: ok I have edited my answer accordingly.